# NextJs - all the aspects of deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, build, next.js13

I want to understand the deployment process of NextJs applications keeping in mind that it provides various ways to deploy different kind of applications, for example, we have Dynamic websites which creates routes dynamically and then we have static websites which only have a small bunch of data.
I want to fully understand how Next.js creates deployment builds and how to deploy them manually on different kinds of servers.

My specific use case here is as follows:
I am currently working on a project which is created using the Next.js framework. We have:

1. Dynamic routes created on runtime and managed through a CMS
2. ServerSideProps and GetInitialProps are being used in the application
3. Using _app.tsx and _document.tsx files to properly maintain these pages
4. Have some static files like icons, fonts, static images, favicon, etc.
5. Have various contexts
6. Have various helper functions
7. Using .env.local for the environment variables

Now, the confusion lies between using the `npm run build` command. I know it's creating a `.next` directory for the optimised build. But when I'm only using this `.next` directory to deploy, it's giving me errors. I have to manually add `package.json`,`next.config.js` and `package-lock.json` files to it as well to make it run. So, what's the actual process for the builds in the Next.js framework works like? How we are supposed to understand the building process? Do we have to use the whole development folder with `.next` folder in the build? Or will it also work only with `.next` folder?
PS. I'm not deploying it on Vercel but using on-premise servers.